# How to apply Row Level Security in below scenario in power bi?

Tags: powerbi

I am importing insurance data (view - having global data ) from Amazon redshift through ODBC connection. I want to apply RLS based on country and contract signed date ( for each country, contract signed date is different.)
Report is published in workspace (new workspace type with premium licence applied)

Requirement is to  create role for each country and create one role as a global where we will see  the data for all country after particular date(date column is available in view)

I want to assign 2 roles to single user.
For ex. XYZ person want to see global data as well as Australia's data.
Can you tell me what will be the output for this?

Is it possible to apply Row Level Security in above scenario ?

Answer (score 0):

I think, there is no need to create two role for single user.

If you give user to global role then user can view global data and even he can filter for Australia's data. If you are putting country filter in the reports.